# Tracking pages as they are created

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

It'd be best if I ask my question using an example. Say I have a website "website.com" and users can make post on this website which correspond to the url "website.com/post/#" where '#' is a number corresponding to the post number.

I'm currently looking at Google Analytics and Heap Analytics and I was wondering if one of these 2 or maybe another analytics provider out there can automatically track these posts as they're created so that every time a post is made I don't have to set it up with a tracking number.

Comment: As long as they are  created from some sort of template (e.g. via a Content Management System) that contains the tracking code new pages will be tracked automatically.

Comment: Will the views be separated by posts, meaning will I be able to see the number of views for post 1 and the number of views for post 2, etc.

Comment: Yes of course. Look into the "behavior" reports in Google Analytics, they list stats for each individual page in the tracked site.